# Unable to shut off notifications for test-related items that have link changes

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2, is there a way to turn off e-mail notifications for test-related work items for my projects?  Specifically, when testers make links with user stories or add steps to tests, I get flooded with e-mails.  This didn't used to happen before, and yes, I did something to cause it but don't know what that was.  But I now want to explicitly shut test-related types off.  All my other notification types seem to be working/filtering as desired.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to you description, it seems related to the notification of the work items. You could try to go to the Notification settings and then disable the subscription of "A work item assigned to me is change" to check the result.

If not, please check if you have installed [Email report extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=epsteam.EmailReportExtension) or other email notification extensions.